# Tkinter troubles - Name frame is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import Tkinter

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.CreateWidgets()
    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.LoginButton = Button(Self)
        self.LoginButton["text"] = "Login"
        self.LoginButton.grid()
        self.QUIT_Button = Button(self)
        self.QUIT_Button["text"] = "Quit"
        self.QUIT_Button["command"] = self.quit
        self.QUIT_Button["fg"] = "red"

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the youtube tutorial that I have been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCLTv6wh3jE&index=39&list=PLB0701884E5AE1B45

And this is the error that keeps occurring:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omer\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Application(Frame):
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
```

I am a complete noob at Python and am still learning so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Frame` `Tk`, and `Button` are all located in the `Tkinter` namespace.  Thus, you have to qualify them to let Python know where they are<sup>1</sup>:

```
import Tkinter

class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
...
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
...
        self.LoginButton = Tkinter.Button(self)
...
        self.QUIT_Button = Tkinter.Button(self)
...

root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

That, or you could just import the names directly:

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Button
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If you decide to use this first solution, it would probably be best to import `Tkinter` like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

That way, the code becomes this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
...
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
...
        self.LoginButton = tk.Button(self)
...
        self.QUIT_Button = tk.Button(self)
...

root = tk.Tk()
```

which is a lot more brief.

Comment: to make the code a bit more brief, I recommend `import Tkinter as tk; tk.Frame(...); tk.Button(...);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `Frame` in order to use it like you are. As it stands you have imported `Tkinter`, but that doesn't give you access to `Frame`, `Button` or `Tk` the way you've used them. but you either need to do:

```
from Tkinter import Frame
```

or

`from Tkinter import *` (* means 'all' in this case, though this isn't necessary when only using a few modules)

or you could leave your import statement as is(`import Tkinter`) and change your code like so:

```
class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
```

and

```
self.LoginButton = Tkinter.Button(Self)
```

However, I would recommend that if you do this, you do:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

That way, you can do `tk.Frame` and `tk.Button` etc.

For any modules that you want to use from Tkinter you need to import them also in the same fashion.

You can do single line imports like so:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button etc.
```

Check out this info on importing in Python: http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Frame`, `Button`, `Tk`.

You can either explicitly import all of them from `Tkinter`:

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Button, Tk
```

or import everything from `Tkinter` (which is [not a good thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)):

```
from Tkinter import *
```

or leave your import as is (`import Tkinter`) and get `Frame`, `Button` and `Tk` from the `Tkinter` namespace, e.g. for `Frame`:

```
class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
```

---

Even better would be to import tkinter in a universal way that would work for both python2 and python3:

```
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk 
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk 

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.CreateWidgets()
    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.LoginButton = tk.Button(self)
        self.LoginButton["text"] = "Login"
        self.LoginButton.grid()
        self.QUIT_Button = tk.Button(self)
        self.QUIT_Button["text"] = "Quit"
        self.QUIT_Button["command"] = self.quit
        self.QUIT_Button["fg"] = "red"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Also, you have a typo, replace (watch `Self`):

```
self.LoginButton = Button(Self)
```

with:

```
self.LoginButton = Button(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a bit late but for someone having same error, be sure there is no `tkinter.py` file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error too. The issue with mine is I had a file called `tkinter.py` and that was overriding the built-in file `tkinter`. So to fix it, I changed my filename to something else.